# How to give custom link overlay name for arrows on the google street view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to show the custom name of the link in `google street view` as an overlay. But custom link name or description is not showing in the street view along with arrow .I am using `google map v3`. Please help me out with that.

[I want to change the street name in the google street view .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BB2R.png)

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Street View image viewer doesn't support this feature.

The problem was reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35831007

Feel free to star this issue and add comments to express your interest and subscribe to notifications from Google.